# Make shell prompt wait till all processes complete

Tags: bash, shell, process, scrapy

I am running a shell script from a java program. The shell script will start multiple scrapy crawlers.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/renny/Documents/WorkSpaces/Scrapy/tutorial

scrapy crawl flipkart -a key="$1" -o "$2"flipkart.xml
scrapy crawl myntra -a key="$1" -o "$2"myntra.xml
scrapy crawl jabong -a key="$1" -o "$2"jabong.xml
```

The shell script will not wait for the completion of the scrapy crawlers.
I want the shell script to exit only after the subprocesses have completed.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `start` looks like Windows  `cmd`, not shell script. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how the process is called but let's say it's called `scrapy`, then you could achieve this by using a busy wait.

```
while [ $(ps | grep scrapy | wc -l) -ge 1 ]; do 
    sleep 1; 
done
exit 0
```

Or alternatively but equivalently

```
while [[ -n $(ps | grep scrapy) ]]; do 
    sleep 1; 
done
exit 0
```

Comment: I get the following error  ./crawls.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./crawls.sh: line 15: `while[$(ps|grep scrapy|wc -l) ge 1];do'  could you please help me out as I am not really able to figure out what is wrong

Comment: @Renny, note that `[` is a **command** in the shell, not just syntax. As a command, you must separate it from other words with whitespace. Take careful note of **all** the spaces in ShellFish's answer.

Comment: @Renny if these are lengthy commands, consider increasing the sleep to save CPU!